# Serialising System.Strings containing % characters

Tags: json.net

When I try to serialise a string containing a '%' character, the '%' is dropped from the serialised string. Can I change this behaviour?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Maybe you can replace '%' with '%x25 when serialize. '%' is the 'escape' character.

Comment: Replacing % with %% seeems to work :).

Comment: @nabuchodonossor `%` is not the escape character for JSON, `\\` is.

Answer (score 1):

The percent character `%` has no special meaning in JSON (see [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)), so it is unlikely that Json.Net is interfering with your string.  Could there be something else in your code that is removing the percent signs?  Are you running the string through a URL decoder somewhere?

Proof that Json.Net does not remove percents:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("test", "100%");
        jo.Add("url", "http://example.org?foo=%34bar%34");
        Console.WriteLine(jo.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "test": "100%",
  "url": "http://example.org?foo=%34bar%34"
}
```